# Error: ENOOET: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have small problem. In my nodejs/express application i use the passport-local strategy for processing authorization information. Recently I began to receive a message in the my nodejs console:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod, rename
>   'C:\olympus\SRC\Gui\app\sessions\WCe9twVKOmignsse_g3H4Uyml2ACz1W5.json.790444257'
>   -> 'C:\olympus\SRC\Gui\app\sessions\WCe9twVKOmignsse_g3H4Uyml2ACz1W5.json'
>
> at Error (native)

This is very annoying.
How can I remove this messages from my console?

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: You need a full code of my application? My project is fairly large. So, i do not want to load it.

Comment: Something to start with. What middleware did you use for managing sessions?

Comment: I use pasport.js and pasport-local.js. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local

Comment: what about session?

Comment: i use "session-file-store": "^0.2.0".

Comment: Is the `sessions` folder there?

Comment: If the error is always the same, you can try cleaning your cookies as well and see if that resolves the issue.